# setting up one to many relationship using Hibernate, JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to setup one to many relationship using Hibernate/Jpa.

Currently I am getting this exception:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: refund_transaction_item_refund_detail
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:279)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:520)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:365)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunWarMojo.execute(JettyRunWarMojo.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: refund_transaction_item_refund_detail
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1333)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:279)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:520)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:365)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunWarMojo.execute(JettyRunWarMojo.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

**RefundTransaction.java** This is the parent class

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import com.limeroad.commons.RefundRequest;


@Entity
@Table(name = "refund_transaction")
public class RefundTransaction {

  public RefundTransaction() {}

  public RefundTransaction(RefundRequest refundRequest) {
    setOrderId(refundRequest.getOrderId());
    setRefundReason(refundRequest.getRefundReason());
    setCallbackUrl(refundRequest.getCallBackUrl());
    setCreatedBy(refundRequest.getCreatedBy());
    setIdempotenceKey(refundRequest.getClientName() + ":" + refundRequest.getClientKey());
  }

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = ItemRefundDetail.class)
  Set<ItemRefundDetail> itemRefundDetails;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name = "refund_request_id", referencedColumnName = "refund_request_id" )
  public Set<ItemRefundDetail> getItemRefundDetails() {
    return itemRefundDetails;
  }

  public void setItemRefundDetails(Set<ItemRefundDetail> itemRefundDetails) {
    this.itemRefundDetails = itemRefundDetails;
  }

  @Column(name = "refund_reason")
  String refundReason;

  @Column(name = "callback_url")
  String callbackUrl;

  @Column(name = "order_id")
  String orderId;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "com.limeroad.services.payments.factory.LimeroadIdGenerator")
  @Column(name = "refund_request_id")
  String refundRequestId;

  @Column(name = "idempotence_key")
  String idempotenceKey;

  @Column(name = "created_by")
  String createdBy;

  @Column(name = "modified_by")
  String modifiedBy;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "create_date")
  Date createDate;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "last_modified")
  Date lastModified;

  @Column(name = "refund_reason")
  public String getRefundReason() {
    return refundReason;
  }

  @Column(name = "callback_url")
  public String getCallbackUrl() {
    return callbackUrl;
  }

  @Column(name = "order_id")
  public String getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
  }

  @Column(name = "refund_request_id")
  public String getRefundRequestId() {
    return refundRequestId;
  }

  @Column(name = "idempotence_key")
  public String getIdempotenceKey() {
    return idempotenceKey;
  }

  @Column(name = "created_by")
  public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
  }

  @Column(name = "modified_by")
  public String getModifiedBy() {
    return modifiedBy;
  }

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "last_modified")
  public Date getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
  }

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "last_modified")
  public Date getLastModified() {
    return lastModified;
  }

  public void setRefundReason(String refundReason) {
    this.refundReason = refundReason;
  }

  public void setCallbackUrl(String callbackUrl) {
    this.callbackUrl = callbackUrl;
  }

  public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
  }

  public void setRefundRequestId(String refundRequestId) {
    this.refundRequestId = refundRequestId;
  }

  public void setIdempotenceKey(String idempotenceKey) {
    this.idempotenceKey = idempotenceKey;
  }

  public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
  }

  public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
    this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
  }

  public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
  }

  public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
    this.lastModified = lastModified;
  }



}
```

**ItemRefundDetail.java** This is the child class.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Table(name = "item_refund_detail")
@Entity
public class ItemRefundDetail implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4604092182622619714L;

  RefundTransaction refundTransaction;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="refund_request_id")
  public RefundTransaction getRefundTransaction() {
    return refundTransaction;
  }

  public void setRefundTransaction(RefundTransaction refundTransaction) {
    this.refundTransaction = refundTransaction;
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "order_id")
  String orderId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "unique_item_id")
  String uniqueItemId;

  Double amount;

//  @Column(name = "refund_request_id")
//  String refundRequestId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "refund_transaction_id")
  String refundTransactionId;

  @Column(name = "transaction_ref")
  String transactionRef;

  @Transient
  InstrumentType instrumentType;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "order_id")
  public String getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "unique_item_id")
  public String getUniqueItemId() {
    return uniqueItemId;
  }


  public Double getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }

//  @Column(name = "refund_request_id")
//  public String getRefundRequestId() {
//    return refundRequestId;
//  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "refund_transaction_id")
  public String getRefundTransactionId() {
    return refundTransactionId;
  }

  @Column(name = "transaction_ref")
  public String getTransactionRef() {
    return transactionRef;
  }

  @Transient
  public InstrumentType getInstrumentType() {
    return instrumentType;
  }

  public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
  }

  public void setUniqueItemId(String uniqueItemId) {
    this.uniqueItemId = uniqueItemId;
  }

  public void setAmount(Double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
  }

//  public void setRefundRequestId(String refundRequestId) {
//    this.refundRequestId = refundRequestId;
//  }

  public void setRefundTransactionId(String refundTransactionId) {
    this.refundTransactionId = refundTransactionId;
  }

  public void setTransactionRef(String transactionRef) {
    this.transactionRef = transactionRef;
  }

  public void setInstrumentType(InstrumentType instrumentType) {
    this.instrumentType = instrumentType;
  }



}
```

I know I am making some mistake in @OneToMany or @ManyToOne annotation.

UPDATE:
I only have 2 tables in the db, **refund_transaction** and **item_refund_detail**. And I dont't have any table named **refund_transaction_item_refund_detail**. After normalizing the schema, I have added **refund_request_id** in the **item_refund_detail** table for maintaining the relationship.
Probably I need to maintain unidirectional mapping, to achieve this. Please advice.

Comment: Exception says `Missing table: refund_transaction_item_refund_detail`.You may need to check if that table exists in your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing many things wrong. Some of the points:

1. You're using both field and property access. You have to pick one style to be the default (you can then override the default with [`AccessType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AccessType.html) for the desired properties).
2. `@ElementCollection` is used for embedded collections, hence the error you get. You should use `@OneToMany` for this.
3. Don't forget to declare one side of a bidirectional association to be the inverse one (in case of a `@OneToMany` relation, usually that's the entity on the `One` side).